# UWP JS: How to get Culture info

Tags: javascript, uwp, win-universal-app

I want to modify my UWP app to operate slightly differently depending on the platform language. I know I can get the culture info when programming with C#, but this app is written with JavaScript.

I searched MSDN and looked through samples on gitHub but couldn't find any documentation or example indicating how to do it. I wonder if it's possible at all.

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://github.com/winjs/winjs/commit/6e6390770cb365fcffec12f8544bcca4156af62c

Comment: Can you describe exactly what you want to do differently, and when? There might be several options, and language might not be the best trigger.

Comment: @fourwhey This looks like about having different string values for different store packages, and perhaps can be used for indirectly achieving what I said . I was just wondering if there is some api to get current OS language preference.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Well, at the first use of the app, I offer some dictionary help to users. If I know their language preference, I can offer relevant language help. I might use what fourwhey suggests or geolocation api of html5, but if there is a windows api for this already, those looks like unnecessary workarounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create a Windows Runtime component using C# then call this C# component from your JavaScript project. In this scenario, you can write a helper class to get the culture info in the C# Windows Runtime component using [CultureInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netstandard-2.0) class, after that, you can reference this component and call the method of the C# class from your JS project to get culture info.

You can learn details from the offical document:

[Walkthrough: Creating a Simple Windows Runtime component and calling it from JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/walkthrough-creating-a-simple-windows-runtime-component-and-calling-it-from-javascript)

Comment: I didn't know we can integrate C# code into JS like that. Though other solutions discussed in the comment can be more practical in some cases, this is certainly the correct answer.